# Unexpected Error in MYSQL workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
USE `movieinfo`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `Movie_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `movies` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (length <30 && length >480 && year <1929)
THEN 
INSERT into movies
END IF;
END
```

I am trying to create a trigger but I keep getting the `Error Code: 1064` because my syntax is wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you want to validate the data and report an error when the data doesn't look right.  In the more recent versions of MySQL, you can use `[signal][1]`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `Movie_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `movies` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ((new.length < 30 OR new.length > 480) AND new.year < 1929) THEN 
         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
               SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Data error on insert';
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

A `before insert` trigger doesn't need to do an explicit insert into the table (in fact, it can't).  Instead, if it completes successfully, then the data in the `new` record will be inserted.  If you want to stop the insert, you need to generate an error, and `signal` is a good way to do that.